# Add new column with null value to large table

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I have a table with more than 15 mln rows and its size is 6570 MB. I need to add a new column on that table, but it is gonna take too much time.

I tried the following ways but it seems not to finish the process when I run the command:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD created_by text default null

ALTER TABLE table ADD created_by text null

ALTER TABLE table ADD created_by text
```

What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Why would the process take time in that case?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but even with null it is taking too much time

Comment: @SarvarNishonboev it's probably waiting for a lock. Check `pg_stat_activity`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's my bad. You're right, the table was locked and after killing the process, I was able to add a column with null within milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a nullable column in PostgreSQL is actually O(1), and it should take a few milliseconds. It only changes the metadata of the table, no IO.

If you had added a non-nullable column - that's totally different, as it would actually go and write the default value to all rows. And block your table for the entire process.

Statement `ALTER TABLE table ADD created_by text default null` is the same as `ALTER TABLE table ADD created_by text`.

Comment: Does this rule apply to earlier versions of Postgresql? I've 9.4.9 version

Comment: @SarvarNishonboev: the part about adding a nullable column is true for all Postgres versions. Postgres 11 introduced a "fast default" feature, where adding a column with a default value would also result in O(1)